# Fourier coefficient of $\frac{1}{5 + 4\cos(x)}$ wrong

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis

**Bug introduced in 12.3.1 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

I've been trying to use Mathematica to compute the Fourier coefficient of

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{5 + 4\cos(x)},
$$
which is a $2\pi$ periodic function. Inputting

```
FullSimplify[
 FourierCoefficient[1/(5 + 4 Cos[x]), x, n, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, n \[Element] Integers}]]
```

I get as an output

> `-(1/3) (-2)^Abs[n]`

This is clearly wrong as the Fourier coefficient of $f$, it being continuous and periodic, should decay with $n$, which the output from Mathematica does not give. Not only that, the Fourier coefficients should be bounded by 1 via
$$
\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{inx} dx\right| \leq \sup_{x\in [-\pi,\pi)}|f(x)|=1 \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Any insight into why this is happening would be appreciated.

**Edit**

Thank you all for your answers. To summarise, it seems that Mathematica evaluates the above correctly if instead you use either of the following:

```
FullSimplify[FourierCosCoefficient[1/(5 + 4 Cos[x]), x, n], 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

OR

```
Simplify[Integrate[Cos[n*x]/(5 + 4 Cos[x]), {x, -Pi, Pi}], 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
```

OR similar variations of the above.

The bug is strange, and hopefully it shall be fixed soon.

Comment: Have you reported it to WRI?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I have reported this bug to Wolfram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a workaround by making use of the definition:

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[1/(5 + 4 Cos[x])*Cos[n*x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]/(2*Pi),  
Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `1/3 (-(1/2))^n`

It's clear that the sine-coefficients equal zero.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems also to be true that 
````FullSimplify[FourierCosCoefficient[1/(5 + 4 Cos[x]), x, n], 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]
````
works also

Comment: Yes. So does `FullSimplify[
 FourierCosCoefficient[1/(5 + 4 Cos[x]), x, n, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 1}], 
 Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an algebraic way to get both series, the divergent one and the convergent one, which are each geometric series. The equation in `SolveAlways` assumes an even function of `x` that can be expanded in a geometric series in $z=e^{ix}$.

```
fz = 1/(5 + 4 Cos[x]) /. x -> Log[z]/I
sol = SolveAlways[1/(a/z + b) + c + 1/(a z + b) - fz == 0 && a != 0, z]
(*
  1/(5 + (2 (1 + z^2))/z)
  {{a -> -6, b -> -3, c -> 1/3}, {a -> 3/2, b -> 3, c -> -(1/3)}}
*)
```

We develop the positive and negative powers of $z=e^{ix}$ separately:

```
cplus = Hold[SeriesCoefficient[1/(a z + b), {z, 0, n}]] /. sol // 
  ReleaseHold
```

[image]

```
cminus = 
 Hold[SeriesCoefficient[1/(a/ z + b), {z, Infinity, n}]] /. sol // 
   ReleaseHold // ReplaceAll[n -> -n]
```

[image]

```
cn = cplus + (Piecewise[{{c, n == 0}}] /. sol) + cminus // 
   Map[PiecewiseExpand[#, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers] &] //
    Simplify
```

[image]

`Simplify` did not combine `±n` into `Abs[n]` — oh, well.  Check series:

```
Sum[# Exp[I n x], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] & /@
  cn /.
 Sum -> Inactive[Sum]
% // Together // ExpandAll // Together // ExpToTrig // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: We can remove the assumption of evenness by using `SolveAlways[1/(a/z + b) + c + 1/(d z + e) - fz == 0 && a != 0, z]`.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you for providing this